# Can I edit only tags, not question's body?

Tags: bug, tags, edits, suggested-edits

I remember, that 2 - 3 months ago it was possible, but today I couldn't do that. There is a permanent problem with [apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apex) (which means language Apex for Salesforce platform) and [oracle-apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) (which means IDE for developing web-applications). New users often use *apex* instead of *oracle-apex*, and during a certain time I was changing these tags, but today I saw error:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Question is: [Insertion of dynamic select list in HTML code in ApEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179860/insertion-of-dynamic-select-list-in-html-code-in-apex)

Have anything changed in the last two months?

Comment: Maybe [tag:apex] should be renamed [tag:apex-lang], to make the difference more obvious... Anyway, did you suggest edits then too?

Comment: I thought a lot about tag renaming, but can't say surely that it will help. And of course, I would like to have possibility to edit only tags.

Comment: i also wanted to edit a tag in a question but couldn't for the same reason.

Comment: It is a question from several years ago, but nowadays I encountered the exact *I remember, that 2 - 3 months ago it was possible, but today I couldn't do that* clause. Adding a tag is not enough again?